# Is it better to use the prediction interval or the RMSE?

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, prediction-interval, rms, quality-control

[image]
I use a measurement technique $X$ to assess if a good is within production specifications during its manufacturing. $X$ is slow but precise. I wish to find out if I can use a measurement technique $Y$ (faster but more imprecise) to predict if the produced good is within specifications.
The model I use is a simple linear regression $y_i = m_0+ x_i*m_1$, with the fitting parameters $m_0$, $m_1$ and the measurement values $y_i$, $x_i$. The correlarion is weak, but there is one.

I plan to use the 95%-prediction interval to predict for $x_{New}$ if the product is within the specification range. Using $y_{New} = m_0 + x_{New}*m_1$, if $y_{New}^{Lower Prediciton} > Specs$ or  $y_{New}^{Upper Prediciton} < Spec$ then the product is within specifications.

Would it be an option to use cross validation (LOOCV) and the root of the MSE instead?
Say: For $y_{New} = m_0 + x_{New}*m_1$, if $y_{New} + RMSE < Specs$ or $y_{New} - RMSE > Specs$ then product is within specifications.

The idea behind this second approach is that the RMSE does not make assumptions on the underlying distribution. Altough, the RMSE is only an average value.

Comment: RMSE and prediction intervals measure completely different things, you’re comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: But if I am not mistaked in a linear model with Gaussian errors we have that the CI comes from the normal distribution $N(ax_{new}+b,\sigma)$, and $\sigma^2$ would be estimated from the data from the $MSE$. I understand that the estimator may be biased especially for small samples, but the two things are closely related no ?